# setup a navigationController using just one h, m, and xib

Tags: objective-c, ios

I just want to set up a `navigationController` with a `view` that's on the same xib file.

**xib structure**

- `File's Owner`
- `navigationController` -> `Navigation Controller`
- `First Responder`
- `Navigation Controller`
- `navigationController` -> `File's Owner`
- `view` -> `Scroll View`
- `Scroll View`
- `view` -> `Navigation Controller`

**.h**

```
@interface WannaBeNavController : UINavigationController <UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "WannaBeNavController.h"


@implementation WannaBeNavController
@synthesize navigationController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController = navigationController;

    //[self setNavigationController:navigationController];
    //[navigationController setView:self.view];



@end
```

I've tried a number of things with no success. All I see is a blank `navigationController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this is possible with *multiple* files OR on a `controller` `xib` with a `window`, but it doesn't seem as though it is with *just three* files (h, m, and xib).

So here's what I did instead:

- Use a `UIViewController` instead of a `UINavigationController`
- Use a `UINavigationBar` for the bar at the top.
- Add a `UIScrollView` below the `UINavigationBar`
- Enable (check) the *Bounce Vertically* in the `UIScrollView` attributes inspector.
- Make the `UIScrollView` appear to be underneath the `UINavigationBar` for when a user scrolls. I'm not sure how to accomplish this step, but I'll post back instructions when I figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning the navigationController to itself which is probably `nil`.

I would just create a normal ViewController (h,m,xib) without any link to a NavigtaionController (so it is also reuseable in not navigation-based apps ;) ). The NavigationController itself will set the navigationController-property of that viewcontroller.

In code you write sth like:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController"];
UINavigationController *navContr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myVC];
[myVC release];

//[window addSubView: navContr.view]; // or sth similar
window.rootViewController = navContr; // thanks to Paul Lynch for that line of code
```

**edit**:

In case of an tabbarcontroller then just code this:

```
MyViewController1 *myVC1 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController"];
MyViewController2 *myVC2 = [[MyViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController2"];
//...
UINavigationController *nav1 =  [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myVC1];
UINavigationController *nav2 =  [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myVC2];
//...
UITabBarController *tabBarContr = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
[tabBarContr setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nil] animated:NO];

window.rootViewController = tabBarContr;    

[myVC1 release];
[myVC2 release];
[nav1 release];
[nav2 release];
[tabBarContr release];
```

Comment: This would be better, for recent versions of iOS: window.rootViewController = navContr;

Comment: The trick is: there is no `window` because this isn't in the "app delegate" or w/e. It's in a view that is already part of a `UITabBarController`. I know there are other ways to do this, I just want to do it for one view without adding 6+ files to my project.

Comment: take a look at my edit. Setting it as a rootViewController to window is just an example. If you are inside another viewcontroller then you can also write `[self.view addSubView:navContr.view]`. But a NavigationController somewhere inside another view is not likly seen in cupertino and may result in a rejection